# Compiler specific header files

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I just wanted to know if there are certain header files which are specific to certain compilers i.e is there a header file which is specific to gcc compiler but not to devc++ compiler?

And if so, where can I find these sources?
Thanks.

Comment: It’s unclear what you’re asking here. Can you try to explain this more clearly?

Comment: Ok, lets consider <iostream>, it is supported by both these compilers. So I wanted to know if there are certain header files which are supported by a compiler, but may not be supported by other compilers? Is that clear enough?

Comment: Sure there are, tons. But since everybody can write headers (and make them support only one compiler) this question (and especially your second question) doesn’t really make much sense.

Comment: Hmm, that I know but I was not referring to user defined header files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are.

An example is the C++/Cli integration code in Microsoft's C++ Compiler in Visual Studio:

```
#include <vcclr.h>
```

This will work in Visual Studio (resp. it's C++ compiler), but not in GCC or Clang.

Comment: Thank you, but could you tell me how you found that out? I need to find all compiler specific header files

Comment: All? That's a hard task. You should probably consult the compiler's documentation and look for extensions. I 'found' it out because I've used that before.

Comment: “all compiler specific header files” makes no sense, as I’ve explained above. It depends on which libraries you’re using. For instance, the header in this answer is part of a specific library (the “Managed Extensions for C++”). It may help if you told us what you need this for, then we can give you more specific advice.

Comment: Ok, let me explain my problem in more detail. I need to create a program that scans a cpp file and show all the header files included, both user defined and predefined. To do this, I created a database containing all predefined header files. Other than the standard library, I also need to scan for header files which may be specific to certain compilers. So that's why I need to find all such files.